Finding a relation between l, m, n given $a_1l+b_1m+c_1n=d_1$ and $a_2l^2+b_2m^2+c_2n^2=d_2$
In quite a few analytic geometry questions, we need to find the relation between l,m and n given the set of equations :
$$ a_1l+b_1m+c_1n=d_1 $$
$$a_2l^2+b_2m^2+c_2n^2=d_2$$
Is there a general approach we can use to find such a relation?
My approach was to eliminate n from the first equation and to get an equation between l and m, however I ended up with a 2 degree polynomial of l and m and I cannot factorize it down to linear terms. Is there a better way to do it?

For it to factor into linear terms, the intersection should be a pair of lines - which is not always the case, so you shouldn't expect the factorisation to work in general.
